# Are the new forms officially named in Sonic Frontiers: The Final Horizon?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

The ending of the last *Sonic Frontier*'s DLC introduces two new "super" forms during the final battle with "The End".

First, Super Sonic powers up to a new form that is loosely reminiscent of Super Saiyan 2.
This form is called "supersonic2" in the game files. Then he further transforms into yet another new form that the game files call "supersoniccyber".

Forms like Darkspine Sonic and Excalibur Sonic have been officially named in side material and/or official interviews. But I can't find anything about these two.

I am therefore asking: were these two forms ever given an official name outside the game files?

During a podcast on the [Ian Flynn channel](https://youtu.be/F_WrfZN07j4?t=1099), it is claimed that the name "Starfall Super Sonic" was used internally for a while, but given that both Super Sonic 2 and Super Sonic Cyber are mentioned soon afterward, it is hard to even understand if they are talking about one of the two specifically, more yet to see that as an official confirmation of a name.